# Open a HTTP port on Amazon EC2

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I have a Tomcat 7 instance running on port 8080, and would like to run Jenkins on a different port. Another alternative would be to change the Jenkins URL.

**How do I add an entry to the list of allowed ports?**

I have tried running: `sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8181 -j ACCEPT`, but in the AWS console it shows only these ports:

```
0 - 65535       0.0.0.0/0
22 (SSH)        0.0.0.0/0
80 (HTTP)       0.0.0.0/0
443 (HTTPS)     0.0.0.0/0
3306 (MYSQL)    0.0.0.0/0
8080 (HTTP*)    0.0.0.0/0
```

Is it possible to add a HTTP port (8181) via the AWS console?

**Update:**

I already tried adding a custom TCP port, but then it doesn't get the HTTP protocol, and when I select HTTP, I can't specify the port!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In EC2 console, look for the column "Security Group" of your instance. Then go to option "Security Groups" above "NETWORK & SECURITY" in navigation menu on left. It will show up the security group you saw before. Click on it, it will show a split screen where the one is above has 2 tabs: Details and Inbound. Go to Inbound, in port range input 8181 and source the ip you want to allow incoming access to instance.
Don't forget to apply changes.

Comment: Sorry, but it is already there as `8181` and not `8181 (HTTP*)`.

Comment: You can specify any port to be HTTP. It says (HTTP*) to 8080 because that port it's commonly used as HTTP port, after port 80. Amazon engineers decided to have it with * because it's not the default port. If you have opened 8181, you must be able to access your Tomcat. Do you have problems with it ?

Comment: I tried with `<Connector port="8181"...>` and also `8081` which was added to Amazon AWS, but Tomcat doesn't work on these ports, only 8080.

Comment: Never mind, it works on my other computers, but not in curl or any browsers on this computer, so it turned out it worked all along. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Sometimes becides of the AWS settings, the port might be blocked by Windows Firewall. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall.html

Comment: If this is a Windows Server instance, they you'll need to add this inbound rule in Windows Firewall rules. So you need both. Rules in your AWS security group and a rule in Windows Firewall too.

Answer (score 3):

As per Agat, double check the firewall settings on the server itself.  I had the same issue with port 8090 and then I realised I needed to open it in the Windows firewall.