# How to run tomcat7 web app through https over port 8443?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, tomcat7, port, vaadin

I have a vaadin 7 app running on tomcat 7 on an EC2 server. The app runs through port 8080, so I redirect my domain from 80 to 8080 using:

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Now, I need to use an SSL certificate that should run on ports 8443 or 443, but checking my port using `sudo netstat -nlp`, I get this:

```
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2332/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2371/sendmail       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2987/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      3204/java           
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      3151/httpd          
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      2332/sshd           
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      3204/java           
tcp        0      0 :::8009                     :::*                        LISTEN      3204/java           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               2063/dhclient       
udp        0      0 172.30.0.27:123             0.0.0.0:*                               2356/ntpd           
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123               0.0.0.0:*                               2356/ntpd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                 0.0.0.0:*                               2356/ntpd           
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1742   2987/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10316  2151/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9565   1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     9820   1578/udevd          @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
```

So, as I understand, those ports aren't even there...How can I "activate" them and then use them for my https connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to configure your certificate in your tomcat as shown [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) .
Then you should open those ports in the EC2 console as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209049/open-a-http-port-on-amazon-ec2).

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Already did that.....my server.xml contains: `<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />` and `<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="server" keystoreFile="/home/ec2-user/www_domain_com.jks" keystorePass="password" />` as the first link you sent says, any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your catalina.out for errors? Do your HTTPS local request work? What Linux distro are you using? Are you using a firewall? (If Ubuntu/Debian) Have you checked your Iptables?