# How to open 8080 port to listen HTTP request from remote computer in ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssh, tcp, firewall

I have run following command :-

```
  nmap localhost
```

and get following result :-

`Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-08-28 09:52 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00031s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql
8000/tcp open  http-alt
8009/tcp open  ajp13
8080/tcp open  http-proxy`

and when i run same command using IP of this(remote) computer i.e :-

```
nmap 54.149.233.194
```

i got following result :-

`Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-08-28 09:52 UTC
Nmap scan report for ec2-54-149-233-194.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (54.149.233.194)
Host is up (0.00072s latency).
Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
8000/tcp open   http-alt
9000/tcp closed cslistener`

So please tell me how can i open 8080 port for listening http request from remote computer using http://IP_ADDRESS:8080/

A tomcat instance is running on this computer at 8080 port, but i am unable to access it remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your apache is already running on `port 8080` then its very likely that the port is not opened from your aws console.
I visited `54.149.233.194` and could find the apache default page.

Here is a link to how to be able to open [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209049/open-a-http-port-on-amazon-ec2)

Copying the answer shamelessly here

> In EC2 console, look for the column "Security Group" of your instance.
>   Then go to option "Security Groups" above "NETWORK & SECURITY" in
>   navigation menu on left. It will show up the security group you saw
>   before. Click on it, it will show a split screen where the one is
>   above has 2 tabs: Details and Inbound. Go to Inbound, in port range
>   input 8181 and source the ip you want to allow incoming access to
>   instance. Don't forget to apply changes.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

In your tomcat server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       URIEncoding="UTF-8"
       address="0.0.0.0"
       redirectPort="8443" />
```

This will make tomcat to bind to all interfaces in your host.

Comment: @EJP Umm... duplicate to [Here](http://serverfault.com/questions/376292/need-tomcat5-configured-to-listen-on-all-interfaces) . and its an accepted answer though...